# Do I need a flyback diode

Tags: diodes, flyback

Do I need a flyback diode for a 24 volt DC 5.4 watt coil inductive load on my PLC relay?

Comment: Maybe, does the PLC Output have any type of protection built in?

Comment: No. What size, rating of diode? Thanks!

Comment: What PLC are you using? Some have some protection built-in, some specify the diode you need. The S7-1200's for example have a specific diode called out in the manual.

Comment: Crouzet Millennium 3. They show to add a diode for inductive loads  in the minimal manual, so ....

Comment: But don't specify what diode.

Comment: That's because you can use almost any diode as long as it can handle the current through and voltage across the coil.

Comment: Thanks! The closest I can get to the inductive load may be at the terminal block, which supplies about 5 other 24VDV non-inductive loads. Any problem doing this?

Comment: Can I put the diode across the PLC relay? Coil leads are 6" only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need a flyback diode for a 24 volt DC 5.4 watt coil inductive load on my PLC relay?

Yes.

> Crouzet Millennium 3. They show to add a diode for inductive loads in the minimal manual but don't specify what diode.

- For your 24 V DC application the diode needs to have a reverse breakdown rating > 24 V. 50 V would be good.
- At the instant of output turn off the inductance is initially going to continue to drive the current through the diode and it will then decay to zero as energy is lost to the coil resistance and voltage drop across the diode. Therefore the diode should be rated at the load current - or at least peak rated.
- \$ I = \frac {P}{V} = \frac {5.4}{24} = 0.25 \ \mathrm A \$. A 1 A diode would be excellent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft6S1f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A 1N4001, 1 A, 50 V diode meets both criteria above.

Comment: You are excellent!

Comment: Thanks. Wait a day or two to give others a chance to respond and then "accept" the best answer.